# How to change the WordPress Upload directory, if file is uploaded from specific front end page

Tags: wordpress

I am using the Profile Builder Pro Plugin to let users upload files to Wordpress. So the files get uploaded to the standard Wordpress upload folder.
However I need to change the upload directory to a subfolder of the uploads folder, but only if the files are uploaded from a certain front end page.

Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example I use when uploading my custom avatars. Basically you need to add a filter when wp_handle_upload is executed and remove it afterwards, you will also need to add your conditions and generally complete the code to handle posted files, attach them to user or post etc.

```
//UPLOAD FOLDER FILTER FOR AVATAR

      function avatar_upload_dir( $dirs ) {
        $dirs['subdir'] = '/avatars';
        $dirs['path'] = $dirs['basedir'] . '/avatars';
        $dirs['url'] = $dirs['baseurl'] . '/avatars';

        return $dirs;
    }   

//SOME CUSTOM UPLOAD FUNCTION    

    function somefunction() {

    //some code here

        add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'avatar_upload_dir' );
        $uploaded_file = wp_handle_upload( $data['file'], array( 'test_form' => false ) );
        remove_filter( 'upload_dir', 'avatar_upload_dir' );

    //some code here

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create new folder **media** in wordpress directory, then edit the wp-config.php file and this line before

```
define('UPLOADS', 'media');
/*Thats all, stop editing!, Happy blogging*/
```

For more detail check this [link](https://www.webnots.com/change-default-media-upload-folder-wordpress/)